# Arduino select a range of LEDs

Tags: arduino, range

I'm pretty new to Arduino and the coding language that it uses, so I've been having trouble with a simple problem. I want to select a range of values, for instance 1-10. In R, I could do with this with `[1:10]`. What is the syntax for doing the same thing in Arduino?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't one.

You need to do it the old fashioned way with a `for` loop.

```cpp
for (int i=0, n=1; n<=10; n++, i++)
    arr[i] = n;
```